# Get jQuery collection of rows based on array of row indices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got an array of indices (in no particular order) and I need to select all the `<tr>`s in a table based on these indices.

What I've got feels sloppy & inefficient. Is there a better way to write this selector?

For those who like to fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PwnhJ/1/

For everyone else:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>one</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>four</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>five</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>six</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>seven</td>
    </tr>
</table>

var indices = [0,3,4,6];
//What I'd love to do
alert($("tr").eq(indices).length); //returns 0

//What does work, but feels sloppy & inefficient 
var selector = ""; 
$(indices).each(function(i, index){
    selector += "tr:eq(" + index + ")";
    if(i + 1 != indices.length){
        selector += ","
    }
});

alert($(selector).length); //returns 4
```

Any help, comments, suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/aUmNK/1/

```
var indices = [0,3,4,6];

console.log( jQuery( "table tr").filter( function(){
   return jQuery.inArray( this.rowIndex, indices ) > -1; 
}));
```

Comment: Excellent! I knew there had to be a better way. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var indices = [0,3,4,6];

$( "table > tr").filter( function(index){
   return $.inArray(index, indices) > -1; 
});
```